# Highlighting a section of a web page the way SO does with inbox links

Tags: html, css

I want to have a fade-in/fade-out highlight color for a section of a web page that was jumped to following a link that was formatted like `<a href="sectiongoto">Link</a>`, where **sectiongoto** identifies a name/ID element.

This would work in the same way as clicking on a Stack Overflow inbox link indicating that you have a new message. When you are navigated/jumped-to the post in question, the post's background fades in with an orange hue and then fades out.

How can I implement this effect on a site I'm currently working on? I looked through the source code of SO's pages using Firebug, but didn't see anything that linked up.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/management

Comment: Why are you linking me to management?

Comment: jQuery an option or does it have to be 100% CSS?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be CSS i just assumed it was. What is your recommendation in jquery?

Comment: may be they can help you and tell you how they develop so :-) i dont know why this question is still open !!!

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for the :target psuedo class

I have not yet looked at SO scripts, but Im fairly certain that the fade is a JavaScript thing.  It can be done with CSS transitions, but that's usually for things like fade in and out of color for hover/focus.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#target-pseudo

http://caniuse.com/#search=target

Assuming you have sample markup like this

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#target1">Go To 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#target2">Go To 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="target1"><!--Your HTML Here --></div>
<div id="target2"><!--Your HTML Here --></div>
```

You then want CSS like this

```
div:target { background-color:orange; }
```

so that when your user clicks a link in the list, your url takes the hashcode #target1 or #target2, and the applicable target in the page now has a background color of orange.

Comment: Cool, the `:target` thing is kinda awesome :-)

Answer (score 1):

So.. what you need to look at is the concept of using a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) within the URL.

> **Extract from the wikipedia entry**
>   <sub>*emphasis is mine</sub>
>
> ...a fragment identifier is a short string of characters that **refers
>   to a resource that is subordinate to another**, primary resource. The
>   primary resource is identified by a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI),
>   and **the fragment identifier points to the subordinate resource**.

I prefer to call it URL hash tags simply because the method used to retrieve them in JavaScript is
`window.location.hash`.  Call it what you want - here is the explanation :

Lets take the URL of my answer as an example:
<sub>Aha! But how did I have the URL before posting this? ;)</sub>

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017592/highlighting-a-section-of-a-web-page-the-way-so-does-with-inbox-links/10036643#10036643`

So the hash value is the `#10036643` at the end of the URL.  You can get to that value by inspecting the `window.location.hash` variable.  The same syntax can be used to add elements to the hash list -
`window.location.hash += "#more_info"`

Multiple key and value pairs can be created easily to store more info :
`http://foobar.com/#one=1#two=2#three=3`

`window.location.hash` will now give us :  `#one=1#two=2#three=3`
And from there we can simply use the [`.split()`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php) function with the `#` character as the delimiter.  That should give you something like this :

```
["", "one=1", "two=2", "three=3"]
```

Pop the first empty element off the array and then for each key/value pair you could do an additional `.split('=')` or simply don't use keys for the values, just have the hash values like this :
`http://foobar.com/post/how-to/#COMMENT_ID`

### Ok,

Now that we know how to embed info into the URL we can start to parse it.  For the sake of this example we'll assume a simple HTML structure like this -

```html
...
<body>
  <div>
    Page Header
  </div>
  <div class="blog_post">
    An interesting section of content.
    <div class="comment cid0" ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="blog_post">
    More fantastic information (and a special offer).
    <div class="comment cid0" ></div>
    <div class="comment cid1" ></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Page Footer
  </div>
</body>
...
```

Given this URL :  `http://foobar.com/post/how-to/#cid1`
You could use some JavaScript in the `document.ready` function to control where to draw the focus -

```
$(function(){
  // Extract comment id from URL
  var targetElementId = window.location.hash.split("#")[1]; // This gives us 456
  var targetElement = $(".comment ."+targetElementId);
  var targetElementOffset = targetElement.offset(); 
  $('body').scrollTop(targetElementOffset.top);

  // Insert highlight functionality here
});
```

With regard to the highlighting, I think that [Kerian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10018294/558021) pretty much covers it - you'll need to use some browser dependent features such as [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions).
You might be able also to get away with some alternatives - you can use these suggestions to spark your imagination -

- placing a repeated 1x1px of slightly transparent color *behind* all the content in that element and simply use the `.fadeOut()` function to hide it after a certain delay.
- animating a background image with `background-position`
- perhaps cycling through some predefined `background-color` properties with `setInterval` callbacks